# how to collect an array passed by laravel controller and retrieve it by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

how to collect an array passed by laravel controller and retrieve it by javascript.  I have a controller which to the laravel view passes an array called retiquetas which I want to retrieve in javascript, I need to know how to retrieve an array passed by the controller. **ERROR Array to string conversion**

**Controller**

```
   $etis = EtiquetaPresupuesto::where('presupuestos_id', $id)->get();
    // Log::info("etis: " . $etis);
    $cadenaEtiquetas = "";
    $contador = 0;
    $idEtiquetas=[];
    foreach ($etis as $eti) {
        $cadenaEtiquetas .= $eti->etiqueta->nombre;
        array_push($idEtiquetas, $eti->etiquetas_id);
        if ($contador != count($etis) - 1) {
            $cadenaEtiquetas .= ", ";
        }
        $contador++;
    }

 return view('presupuestos_contabilidad/info-presupuestos', [

        'etiquetas_id' => $idEtiquetas,
])
```

**Javascript**

```
var etiquetas=<?php echo $etiquetas_id; ?>;
```

Comment: One option is to `json_encode` the array in your controller and then parse/use the JSON object in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately you currently cannot fetch an array directly from php to js. Encode it in json (json_encode) and get it via ajax in js